# Why can't I set my input field with MooTools?

Tags: javascript, forms, events, input, mootools

Ive got a document and when the user enters something into one input I need to show a response in a second input box. I can get the user given value, i can process it, but when I try to set the second input box with the result I get the error $.field is null. Here is the code:

```
$('places').addEvent('keyup', function(){
    var places = $('places').value;
    alert("PLACE: "+places);
    var price = values[places];
    var nights = $('nights').value.toInt();
    alert("NIGHTS: "+nights);
    var total = price * nights;
    alert("TOTAL: "+total);
    $('pricepernight').set('text', total);
    $('pricetotal').set('text', total - ((total / 100) * 21));
});
```

So I get the place value. I pull the price of the place out of an assoc array. I then multiple that price by the amount of nights field in by the user and this is then my total amount. It is this amount that I cannot set to. Note that the alert shows the correct amount.

and the html looks like this

```
<div class='block'>
    <input type="text" id="places" />
</div>

<div class='block'>
    <label for="nachten">Aantal nachten</label>
    <input type="text" id="nights" />
</div>

<div class='block long'>
    <span class='label'>Prijs per slaapplaats per nacht</span>
    <input type="text" class='resultfield' id='pricepernight' />
</div>
<div class='block last'>
    <span class='label'>Totaalprijs excl. btw</span>
<input type="text" class='resultfield' id='pricetotal'/>
</div>
```

Firebug responds:

```
String contains an invalid character
[Break On This Error]   

...x:\'4W\',3X:18.1l,al:18.1l,1Q:18.1l,as:18.1l,8S:18.1l,1F:O,3E:{x:\'1u\',y:\'1o\'...
```

Any ideas/suggestions anyone? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may also be worth noting that I am using MooTools.

Comment: MooTools?  Not jQuery?  If you're using MooTools, why is the question tagged jQuery, and why is jQuery in the title?    `$('nights').addEvent` is not jQuery.  Seems like you are confusing/mixing up MooTools and jQuery.

Comment: In some places you are using MooTools' `document.id` shortcut (`$('places')`), while later you are using jQuery (`$("#pricepernight")`)?

Comment: Ok so I'm definately mixing the two up then. Looks like I got to do some reading up on this stuff. I'm new to both. Edited tags and title. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right. you seem to have used a mix of mootools and jquery code.

```
$('nights').addEvent('keyup', function(){
    var places = $('places').value;
    var price = values[places];
    var nights = $('nights').value;
    var total = price * nights;
    alert(total);
    $('#pricepernight').val(total);
    //$('#pricetotal').val(total - ((total / 100) * 21));
});
```

in mootools 1.2+, this should be:

```
$('nights').addEvent('keyup', function(){
    var places = $('places').get('value');
    var price = values[places];
    var nights = $('nights').get('value');
    var total = price * nights;
    alert(total);
    $('pricepernight').set('value', total);
    //$('#pricetotal').val(total - ((total / 100) * 21));
});
```

there's an implied global array values. also, this is not very safe as nights may not be integer.

the point is. `#id` -> `id` and `.val()` -> `set('value', 'newvalue')` - or `.get('value')`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. Things are slowly getting clearer :) I updated my code to what I had prior to your response. I will see if I can get it to work now!

Comment: yeah check this. http://jsfiddle.net/RcTLu/ - proves it can now work fine though I have gone with a dropdown and a prices map that matches to make it easier - i guess in your case, things will be more complex - eg, loose typing: http://jsfiddle.net/RcTLu/2/ until it hits a match.

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome. Great example and site. I'd +1 you if I had enough rep :P Thank you!

Comment: What would the mootool equivalent of .get be? Any idea? Firebug telling me that .get is not a valid function:

$("places").get is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var places = $('places').get('value');

Comment: ah - if you are on an old version of mootools, then it's `.getProperty()` - 1.2+ it's `.get`. supporting 1.1x is not a good idea, you should look into upgrading... and even though you cannot upvote, you can accept an answer if it helped you solve your problems :)

Comment: hmmm almost there. My string contains an invalid charactor but parsing it with String.from doesn't help. Am I right in assuming its a type problem? Or is there something else going on? Don't quite understand why your example works fine while mine is throwing all these type errors :P

Comment: i would say, scrap alert and go to `console.log`, i got the same error as you initially but as i rewrote it and stopped going to element properties directly, it stopped... if you want, update the jsfiddle to post your code with the exception and i will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the jsfiddle and it works there. Completely. Yet local it does not. Thats pretty weird. Must be some settings or so?

Comment: what version of mootools do you have locally? are there any special chars outside of the 'normal' english charset? if you want, come to irc.freenode.net #mootools and ping me (nick coda), will look further.

Comment: Found it. $('pricepernight').value = total; works instead of .set. It is now up and running nicely. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: .set() -> .setProperty() in older mootools

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#nights').keyup(function(){
    var places = $('#places').val();
    var price = values[places];
    var nights = $('#nights').val();
    var total = parseInt(price) * parseInt(nights);
    alert(total);
    $('#pricepernight').val(total);
    //$('#pricetotal').val(total - ((total / 100) * 21));
});
```

and what is `values[places]`?

Comment: values[] is an assoc array with a bunch of prices in it. The user enters an int (1-10) and chooses which place. (I know...but this is the way the client wants it done). The price then gets pulled out of the array based on the index the user gave.

Comment: FYI as opposed to using [] notation some feel it is easier to read using dot notation so var price = values[places] could be var price = values.places ALSO if you would like it to default incase for some reason values.places is undefined you could go one step further and do price = values.places || 0; where 0 could be any integer or you could wrap in quotes to place a default string.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of minor mistakes here.

1. First, you should use # sign to select based on your id attributes
   like places and nights

   Check http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
2. Second, use val() to read the value from the html controls rather
       than value

   Check http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I use # to access my input field with id "pricepernight". Is this not what you meant or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: You do it correctly for id "pricepernight" but not for id "places" and "nights" . aslo you need to parse numbers (http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Parsing_Numbers) since you are doing calulations which will not work on strings and may give awkward outputs.